# Community Wiki guidance lacking

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, meta-faq

I just reread the top-level faq. While it mentions the rep impact of community wiki, it offers no suggestion or advice as to when if ever a new user might be well-advised to check the 'community wiki' box on a question.

Then I read the community wiki [official FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow/11747#11747) answer.

And the top-scoring, accepted, answer also offers no guidance as to when to check the box. It talks about 'posts,' but has nothing specific to say about questions versus answers. Further, the giant clutter of debate in the comments led me to abandon all hope of asking for clarification in this regard by posting a comment. So I'm posting this question to appeal to someone who feels up to it to enhance that answer.

Comment: New users don't see a CW check box.

Comment: (a) that makes it more confusing, and (b) from personal experience, I can tell you that no magical process enlightens a person when they get enough rep to see the box.

Comment: I doubt that there's anything that you could add to the top-level faq that would make CW any less confusing to a new user than it already is.

Comment: Unless there's a 1-day Stack-Exchange beginner's course. I wonder how many will attend?